# How to make the flask app ask questions one by one to a user and keep the answers of that user?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, twilio

I want to build a simple chat bot using twilio, whatsapp and flask that will ask the user about name,age and a picture. But the flask app just asks one question and returns the output and exits from the function.

I have tried using a while loop to keep on asking all questions and get the output, but without a return the response to the users message won't display. Hence I cannot get the answer to my next question for the user.
Is there any way to like create a session for a user and get all the details and close the session, and the next time the same user initiates the chat the user can get their information.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

output = []

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world !!"

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_reply():
    # Fetch the message
    msg = request.form.get('Body')
        msg = msg.lower()
    output.append(msg)

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message("May I know you name?")

    # ASK ANOTHER QUESTION

    print("User message: ", msg)

    return str(resp)
```

Comment: This isn't how REST works. https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest what you could do is display a (html) page where you ask the username, age and picture and send those details in a POST request to your server. That's it. Make sure to do **at least** server sided verification of the data.

Comment: Means I have to provide all the details in one go and save the entire response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyo, Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

Assuming that your `/sms` endpoint is what you defined as webhook URL when a message comes in what you can do is [to use cookies to persist the state of your conversation](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html). If you set a cookie for the webhook request, this cookie will persist for the following webhooks (for max of 4h).

I'm not a python dev but I build [a quick JS example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hexagonal-burglar?path=server.js:41:0) that has an [`/sms/` endpoint available](https://hexagonal-burglar.glitch.me/sms). The logic is fairly straight forward and should be transferable to flask. :)

In pseudo code what you can do is to persist state via the set cookies.

- check the state of the cookies
- if nothing is set, set a state cookie like `state=asked_for_name`
- return TwiML to ask for the name
- **Your number gets a response asking for a name and the person answers with their name. Another webhook is sent to the same URL.**
- check the `state` cookie and find `asked_for_name`
- set a `name` cookie with the value of the webhook body `response.Body.body`
- change the state cookie to `state=asked_for_age`
- return TwiML to ask for the age
- **Your number gets a response asking for age and the person answers with their age. Another webhook is sent to the same URL.**
- check the `state` cookie and find `asked_for_age`
- set a `age` cookie with the value of the webhook body `response.Body.body`
- change the state cookie to `state=sent_summary`
- return TwiML including `name` and `age`

[image: Example whatsapp conversation asking for name and age]

As a side note, for these kind of things you might want to check out [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio). You can build these chat conversations by dragging and dropping some widgets in no time. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and consideration :-) It worked in flask. I will surely checkout Twilio Studio :-)

Comment: That's great! Happy to help. ‍♂️